# how to see what row is selected in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I am trying to get the value of the row selected in a Jtable but am so confused on how to implement the ListSelectionListener so that I can see what has been selected. I have gone to the java tutorial but i find it confusing. can anyone give me an example on how to create a ListSelectionListener and handle an event where a user selects a row?

Answer (score 2):

> am so confused on how to implement the ListSelectionListener

See: [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for a working example.

> I have gone to the java tutorial but i find it confusing.

We don't know what you find confusing about the working example from the above tutorial. So why do you think any code we post would be any different? Unless you can state the exact problem you have (along with your SSCCE) we can't offer any more help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the code at;

http://www.coderanch.com/t/339330/GUI/java/values-selected-row-JTable

I think, it'll help you.

Comment: I am still confused. My program only has two methods: my main method and my action performed method. i am trying to create another method that would handle the ListSelectionEvent like so:

    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent d) {
  if (e.getSource = ) {
  }
 }
the link you sent me has multiple methods in it which one is actually getting the row values?